# Multiple attribute values .attr() jquery method

Tags: jquery

I am able to get the 'href' attribute value and need to get 'rel' attribute/property value as well. How can i add one more attribute 'rel' to the below code.

```
$('.fitcolorslist').find('img:first').wrap('<a/>');

$('.fitdetials a').attr('href', function() {
    return $(this).closest('.fitcolorslist')
        .find('.containerresults li a:first')
        .attr('href');
});
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to copy the `rel` attribute from the same element? Or do you want to access the `rel` attribute within the current `attr()` call you have to set the `href`?

Comment: Want to copy the rel attribute from the same from where i am getting the href value.

Comment: In that case you need to just duplicate that function and change the property you copy.

Comment: Duplicating the function is fine, just want to check is there any better option instead of that(assume more than 2+ attributes).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Want to copy the rel attribute from the same from where i am getting the href value.

Simple enough, just use `each` instead of `attr` and set both attributes inside the callback for each element:

```
$('.fitdetials a').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var $src = $this.closest('.fitcolorslist')
                    .find('.containerresults li a:first');
    $this.attr({
        href: src.attr('href'),
        rel:  src.attr('rel')
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for quick response..:)